# Why i can just showed comments for odd post? is there any logic error? pls help to fix it

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

All. I'm facing a problem which is creating a post page like "FB" which consist of multiple post in a page. And I wrote a the controller function like this:

```
public function getPosts(Request $request){
        $user=User::all()->where('id',Auth::id()); //passing to input post in current.blade
        $users=User::all()->where('id',Auth::id()); //passing to data.blade which seperate file

        $posts=Content::with('comments')
        ->leftjoin('users','contents.UserID','=','users.id')
        ->leftjoin('content_attachments','contents.id','=','content_attachments.ContentID')
        ->select('contents.*','contents.id as pid','users.name','users.userAvatar','content_attachments.*')
        ->orderBy('contents.created_at', 'DESC')
        ->paginate(5);
    
        //ajax for infinite scroll
        if($request->ajax()){
            $view=view('data')->with('user',$user)->with('users',$users)->with('posts',$posts)->render();
            return response()->json(['html'=>$view]);
        }
        // dd($posts);
        return view('community')->with('user',$user)->with('users',$users)->with('posts',$posts);
    }
```

But the result is
1st post has comment showed
2nd post cannot display comment (no array passing)
3rd post has comment showed (but its for 2nd post)
4th post cannot display comment (no array passing)
5th post has comment showed (but its comment for 3rd post)
Output:
[post view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blx7r.jpg)

Comment model:

```
    public function content(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Content');
    }
    
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
```

Content Model(post):

```
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function contentAttachment(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ContentAttachment')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment');
    }
```

User Model:

```
    public function comment(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment');
    }

    public function content(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Content');
    }
```

data.blade:
which specific for post passing

```
@foreach($users as $users)
   @foreach($posts as $post)
      <li>
         <!-- begin timeline-time -->
            <div class="timeline-time">
               <input type="hidden" id="postID" value="{{$post->pid}}">
               <span class="date" id="date{{$post->pid}}">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($post->ctDate)->format('d F') }}</span>
               <span class="time">{{$post->ctTime}}</span>
            <!-- </a> -->
            </div>
            <!-- end timeline-time -->
            <!-- begin timeline-icon -->
            <div class="timeline-icon">
               <a href="javascript:;">&nbsp;</a>
            </div>
            <!-- end timeline-icon -->
            <!-- begin timeline-body -->

            
            <div class="timeline-body">
               <div class="timeline-header">
                  <span class="userimage"><img src="{{ asset('images/user/'.$post->userAvatar) }}" alt=""></span>
                  <span class="username"><a href="javascript:;">{{$post->name}}</a> <small></small></span>
                  <span class="pull-right text-muted">18k Views</span>
                  @if(Auth::id() == $post->UserID)
                  <div class="dropdown">
                     <!-- EDIT -->
                     <span class="icon-right pen" style='font-size:10px' id="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a href="javascript:editPost({{$post->pid}});" class="btn btn-sm btn-default ivm-show edit" style='padding:5px 13px;' data-mdb-toggle="modal" data-mdb-target="#editModal" data-target-detail="{{$post->ctDetail}}" data-target-pid="{{$post->pid}}" data-target-pic="{{ asset('images/post/image/'.$post->ctImage) }}">
                           <i class='fa fa-pen' style='color:whitesmoke;'></i>
                        </a>
                     </span>
                     <!-- DELETE -->
                     <span class="icon-right trash" style='font-size:10px' id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" >
                        <a href="{{route('delPost',['id'=>$post->pid])}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default ivm-show " style='padding:5px 13px;' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this post?')">
                           <i class='fa fa-trash' style='color:whitesmoke;'></i>
                        </a>
                     </span>
                  </div>
                  @endif
               </div>
               
               <div class="timeline-content">
                  <p class="addReadMore showlesscontent" id="postBody{{$post->pid}}"> <!-- class="show-read-more" -->
                     {{$post->ctDetail}}
                  </p>
                  <!-- ----------------------------------------IMAGE------------------------------------------------- -->
                  @if($post->ctImage!=NULL)
                     <img class="postImage zoomable" id="image{{$post->pid}}" src="{{ asset('images/post/image/'.$post->ctImage) }}" alt="{{$post->ctImage}}" onclick="showImage({{$post->id}})">
                  @endif
                  <!-- ----------------------------------------VIDEO------------------------------------------------- -->
                  @if($post->ctVideo!=NULL)
                  <div class="iframe">
                     <iframe id="iF{{$post->pid}}" class="responsive-iframe" src="{{ asset('images/post/video/'.$post->ctVideo) }}" title="video" frameborder="0"  allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" width="auto" height="auto" sandbox="" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  </div>
                  @endif
               </div>
               <div class="timeline-likes">
                  <div class="stats-right">
                     <!-- <span class="stats-text">259 Shares</span> -->
                     <!-- <span class="stats-text">0 Comments</span> -->
                  </div>
                  <div class="stats">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-fw stats-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span>
                     <span class="stats-total" id="stats-total-{{$post->pid}}">
                     @if($post->likedUsers->count() !=0)
                        {{$post->likedUsers->count()+ rand(50,99)}}
                     @else
                        {{rand(50,99)}}
                     @endif
                     </span>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="timeline-footer">
                  <!-- LIKE FUNCTION -->
                  @guest
                     <a href="#" class="m-r-15 text-inverse-lighter"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-fw fa-lg m-r-3"></i> Like</a>
                  @else
                  <div class="like">
                     <a href="javascript:;" class="m-r-15 text-inverse-lighter likeButton" id="like-btn{{$post->pid}}" data-id="{{$post->pid}}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" data-button="like-{{$post->pid}}" data-btnword="like-word-{{$post->pid}}" data-stats="stats-total-{{$post->pid}}">
                     <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-fw fa-lg m-r-3" style="color:{{Auth::user()->likedPosts()->where('content_id', $post->pid)->count() > 0 ? '#02eb0d' : ''}}" id="like-{{$post->pid}}"></i>
                     <h3 style="display: inline-block;font-size:16px;color:{{Auth::user()->likedPosts()->where('content_id', $post->pid)->count() > 0 ? '#02eb0d' : ''}}" id="like-word-{{$post->pid}}">Like</h3></a>
                     <form action="{{route('post.like',$post->pid)}}" method="POST" style="display:none" id="like-form-{{$post->pid}}">@csrf</form>
                  </div>
                  @endguest

                  <!-- pop COMMENT FUNCTION -->
                  <a href="javascript:commentBox({{$post->pid}});" class="m-r-15 text-inverse-lighter"><i class="fa fa-comments fa-fw fa-lg m-r-3"></i> Comment</a> 
                  <!-- SHARE FUNCTION -->
                  <div class="shareContainer">
                     <div class="emojibar" data-id="{{$users->id}}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://127.0.0.1:8000/community" target="_blank"><div class="emoji"><img src="Images/icons/facebook.png" alt=""><p>Facebook</p></div></a>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://127.0.0.1:8000/community" target="_blank"><div class="emoji"><img src="Images/icons/twitter.png" alt=""><p>Twitter</p></div></a>
                        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://127.0.0.1:8000/community&title=Share+title&summary=There+will+be+a+window+left" target="_blank"><div class="emoji"><img src="Images/icons/linkedin.png" alt=""><p>LinkedIn</p></div></a>
                        <a href="https://wa.me/?text=http://jorenvanhocht.be" target="_blank"><div class="emoji"><img src="Images/icons/whatsapp.png" alt=""><p>WhatsApp</p></div></a>
                     </div>
                     <a class="m-r-15 text-inverse-lighter share"><i class="fa fa-share fa-fw fa-lg m-r-3"></i> Share</a>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <!-- COMMENT SHOW-->
               <div class="timeline-comment-box" id="comment{{$post->pid}}" style="display: none;">
                  @foreach($post->comments as $comment)
                  <div class="comment-list">
                     @if($comment->UserID == 1)   
                     <div class="user"><img src="{{ asset('images/user/ghost.jpg') }}"></div>
                     <span class="username">George</span>
                     @elseif($comment->UserID ==2)
                     <div class="user"><img src="{{ asset('images/user/guest1.png') }}"></div>
                     <span class="username">Ved</span>
                     @else
                     <div class="user"><img src="{{ asset('images/user/user.jpg') }}"></div>
                     <span class="username">David Lee</span>
                     @endif
                     <div class="input comment-detail">
                        <p>{{$comment->cmDetail}}</p>
                     </div>
                     @if(Auth::id() == $comment->UserID)
                     <div class="dropdown">
                        <!-- DELETE -->
                        <span class="icon-right-comment trash" style='font-size:10px' id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" >
                           <a href="{{route('delComment',['id'=>$comment->id])}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default ivm-show " style='padding:6px 13px;' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this comment?')">
                              <i class='fa fa-trash' style='color:whitesmoke;'></i>
                           </a>
                        </span>
                     </div>
                  @endif
                  </div>
                  @endforeach
                  <!-- ADD COMMENT  -->
                  <div class="user"><img src="{{ asset('images/user/'.$users->userAvatar) }}"></div>
                  <div class="input">
                     <form action="{{route('addComment')}}" method="POST" id="comForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @CSRF
                        <div class="input-group">
                           <input type="hidden" name="userId" id="userId" value="{{$users->id}}">
                           <input type="hidden" name="postId" id="postId" value="{{$post->pid}}">
                           <input maxlength="200" type="text" name="comment" id="comment" class="form-control rounded-corner" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Write a comment..." required/>
                           <span class="input-group-btn p-l-10">
                           <button class="btn btn-primary f-s-12 rounded-corner btn-color addcomment" type="submit" data-id="{{$users->id}}">Comment</button>
                           </span>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         <!-- end timeline-body -->
      </li>
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comments table in phpmyadmin:
[comment db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NyTw.png)

Contents table in phpmyadmin:
[content db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRfwG.png)

Comment: I have had similar confusing issues with join tables. And those were due to id column.  You can change this  - select('contents.*','contents.id as pid','users.name','users.userAvatar','content_attachments.*') - Instead of contents.* , select particularly required columns only from contents table.  Though not 100% sure about it.

Comment: Just looking at the first two lines of code and the comments, there are already lots of questions and contradictions there. Maybe you need to revert to the last working version, then refactor the code, then try to apply the previous changes on top of that. It's unclear though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead you can do like this

```
$posts = Content::with('comments.user')
->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
->paginate(5);
```

as a result your comments are contained within each post object.
it is much easier to loop over posts with a query like this

Comment: Thx, it works! but there's still some bug need to fix.
which are
1) in data.blade, how can i display user picture (user.userAvatar) for each comment?
Because now i'm using the worst way (if else check userID) to display name and userAvatar.
2) And without leftjoin on user table, my {{$post -> userAvatar}} can't show on each post

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/84Ofz.png

Comment: I solved 2) by leftjoin only userAvatar